# how to find image of $w=z^2$ for one complex sector

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

how to find image of $w=z^2$ for one complex  sector given by $|z|=\frac{4}{3}$ and $-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq \operatorname{Arg} z\leq \frac{\pi}{6} $. Well, the answer say something like this:

$\text{arc}\{v=0, 0\leq u\leq 1\}, \{u=0, 0\leq v\leq 2\} $ and $\{u=1-\frac{v^2}{4}, 0\leq v\leq 2\}$. Honestly i believe that maybe it has one mistake.

I tried with the polar way, so if $z=re^{i\theta}$ then $z^2=r^2e^{i2\theta}$ implies the new region is : $R=\frac{16}{9}$ and $ -\pi \leq Arg w\leq \frac{\pi}{3}$. But when i tried to put in cartesian way, i dont know how to arrive in the answer.

$z^2= x^2-y^2+i2xy$ so i  thought that maybe i need to put $u=x^2-y^2$ and $v= 2xy$ and defined $w=u+iv$ and use $-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq \tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}\leq \frac{\pi}{6} $.

When i take u like a constant i find relation between them, like $v= 2y \sqrt{u+y^2}$, but anyway is work for me. Please somebody can help me?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe is the direction (i believe this) i am not sure, of $ 0$ to $\frac{\pi}{6} $ counterclokwise and  from $0$ to $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ clockwise, sorry but the problem say that. How to fix? thank you

Comment: Sorry, I skimmed the $-$ sign. I deleted my comment.

Comment: not worries, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your computations are fine. The original region is an arc of the circle centered at $0$ with radius $\frac43$, which goes from $\frac43e^{-\pi i/2}\left(=-\frac43i\right)$ to $\frac43e^{-\pi i/6}$; it's the blue arc from the picture below. And it is transformed into  an arc of the circle centered at $0$ with radius $\frac{16}9$, which goes from $\frac{16}9e^{-\pi i}\left(=-\frac{16}9\right)$ to $\frac{16}9e^{-\pi i/3}$; it's the red arc from the picture below.

[image]

Comment: thank you Jose Carlos Santos, but how to arrive in the answer, do you believe that the expression is fine in the answer of my professor? when he put  in terms of $u$ and $v$. Thank you again

Comment: I don't know what more do you thank that it is needed here other than the fact that $z=\frac43e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta\in\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi6\right)$ is equivalent to $z^2=\frac{16}9e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta\in\left(-\pi,\frac\pi3\right)$.

Comment: i believe the same, maybe the professor has one mistake in your answer. Thank you

Comment: *What* is the answer of your professor?

Comment: In the post of the question i put arc $\{v=0, 0 \leq u \leq 1\}$, $\{u=0,0\leq v\leq 2\}$ and $\{u=1-\frac{v^2}{4}, 0\leq v\leq 2\}$....thank you